# How can I change data programmatically?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have a named OData version 4 source in my SAPUI5 application. I need to manipulate object data in a button click event handler like this:

```
var oContext = evt.getSource().getBindingContext("dsName"); // works
var sPath = oContext.getPath() + "/myPropertyName";

// Approach 1 for setting value to true:
oContext.getModel().setProperty(sPath, true); // not working

// Approach 2:
var item = evt.getSource().getBindingContext("dsName").getObject();
item.myProperty = true; // not working
```

The only way I managed to change the property value was by two-way-binding it to a control (check input). Can someone tell me if and how it is possible to update OData v4 models in code?

Comment: oData Models by-default are one-way bound. You will have to explicitly set binding as two way by using method : `setDefaultBindingMode` :https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Model/methods/setDefaultBindingMode. Moreover, if there are many manipulations in client side, then I would recommend you store the binding context in a JSON Model and then fire update/create using oData Model.

Comment: My model is two-way bound. Updating by letting the user change values of controls is working. What doesn't work is manipulation the data directly in code.